# Change Markdown preview theme in Atom

Tags: css, markdown, atom-editor

Is there a way to change the theme of the Markdown preview in Atom by using cascading stylesheet (CSS) files? I'm using the [`markdown-preview-plus`](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview-plus) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this can be done using CSS, as you indicated. The [markdown-preview package's documentation](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) has an example:

```
.markdown-preview.markdown-preview {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Take a look at the `less` source files in the markdown-preview package for some further information on the available style classes that you can override: https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/blob/master/styles/markdown-preview-default.less

Comment: So, what are you waiting for? You should be able to just paste the above into your Atom user stylesheet...